# How do I move a Web References from one project to another in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-reference

I'm doing some solution housecleaning and want to move a few web references from one project to another. VS2010 will not let me drag/drop them from one project to another. What is the easiest way to move them? If it matters these are old-style asmx web services, not WCF services.

Comment: Why not just readd them to the new project?

Comment: Because you don't want to dig up the WSDL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you'll have to manually copy the folders. And then edit the project file in a diff tool like Beyond Compare.

Actually a thought - can you not add the project to the current solution and copy/paste or drag copy?

Comment: Tedious but functional. I'll accept this if no one has a better idea by tomorrow.